# How to manually pass a trace (correlation) ID from a console app to ASP.Net Core and affect Activity.Current.TraceId

Tags: c#, trace, .net-6.0, system.diagnostics, telemetry

I am trying to pass a "Request-Id" header from a front-end (console) application to a back-end ASP.Net Core service (.NET 6) and expecting the **Activity.Current.TraceId** property to have the same value.  The **Activity.Current.TraceId** on the back-end is resulting in an empty GUID when I specify the "Request-Id" header.  When I don't specify the header, it creates a new GUID.  Am I trying the correct approach?

My actual requirement is to be able to correlate operations in the console app with operations in the back-end ones.  I am trying to do this by allowing the client to pass a custom trace/correlation ID to the back-end server, and then that ID is re-used by the back-end for all its subsequent operations.  The telemetry client to be used is Azure Application Insights, but I disabled it for now to keep things simple and simply observe the trace IDs.

What am I missing?  The code in the console app looks like this:

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/activity/correlationId");
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Request-Id", Activity.Current.TraceId.ToString());

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

UPDATE: I've managed to pass the Request-Id header from the console app to the back-end app using the W3C format, but now I'm having trouble trying to figure out why this request-id won't propagate when sending a request with a new HTTPClient on the back-end server.  To summarize, how do I setup HttpClient in .NET Core to automatically inject trace context header?

Comment: Have you tried a hierarchial `Request-Id`, e.g., `$"|{Activity.Current.TraceId}."`?

Comment: Thanks Stephen!  You helped unblock my tunnel vision. Since I'm on .NET 6.0, the default is W3C, so I tried that format instead (00-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-00) and it worked.  Unfortunately now, I cannot figure out why ASP.NET does not propagate the request-id header from one request to another.  Will update my question.

Comment: It might be a good idea to ask a separate question. I believe Request-Id is AppInsights's header before they switched to W3C. Can you try "traceparent" header? See more details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/

Comment: Hello. Header value example: 
Request-Id: 00-da8344ef287123f92fa04a8c9cb72690-f811cae1dc112257-00